# How to change the Shift+Click hotkey in Safari?

Tags: safari, shortcut

I want `Shift + Click` to open hyperlinks in a new window. The default Safari hotkeys are quite bad:

- `Shift + Click` adds a hyperlink to the Reading List.
- `Command + Option + Shift + Click` opens hyperlinks in a new window.

How do I customize these hotkeys? The usual Keyboard UI for customizing hotkeys doesn't appear to handle hotkeys involving mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable "cmd-click opens a  link in a new tab" in Safari Settings (Tabs) then cmd-click becomes "Opens a link in a new window".